# Imgur API return "undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, image-uploading, imgur

I've the following js code to upload image to imgur using Auth.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.ondragover = function(e) {e.preventDefault()}
    window.ondrop = function(e) {e.preventDefault(); upload(e.dataTransfer.files[0]); }
    function upload(file) {


        if (!file || !file.type.match(/image.*/)) return;


        document.body.className = "uploading";


        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append("image", file);
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "https://api.imgur.com/3/image.json");
        xhr.onload = function() {
            var code = '[img]' + JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).data.link + '[/img]';
            var editor = eval('opener.' + 'clickableEditor');
            editor.performInsert(code);
            javascript:window.close()
        }

        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', '39-letter-client-secret-code');

        xhr.send(fd);
    }
</script>
```

It doesn't uploads image to the imgur, but it returns data "undefined". Can you please mention me if I'm missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen an issue in this line;

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', '39-letter-client-secret-code');
```

I've changed it to;

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Client-ID 15-letter-Client-ID');
```

and it works. Sorry to bother you.